# Write files df in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have script that run over file for each "task" - unique id in my input table. After process, I want to write my output frame as file with name of task separately for each  task. For example: task1.scv, task2.scv and so on.
my code that doesn't work:

```
for t in range(0,len(cv_tasks)):
      <...some process..>
df.to_csv('%s.csv' % cv_tasks[t])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible simplify your task:

```
for i, t in enumerate(cv_tasks):
    print (i)
    print (t)
    <...some process..>
    #indentation necesary
    df.to_csv(f'{t}.csv')
```

Comment: I also use value 't' as assign :   n_rows = int(frame.loc[frame['task']==cv_tasks[t],['last_frame']].to_numpy())+1   , so in you code raise KeyError(key), I stil need save t as integer. When I change code to frame.loc[frame['task']==t, it;s no error but still make only one file

Comment: @TeoK - Added `i` for integers. Answer was edited.